# Do equipment bonuses stack?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3's multiplayer, you can equipment bonuses for your character in the equipment screen:

[image]

My question is, if I equip two bonuses that effect the same stat, will they both stack with each other, or will I only get the benefit of whichever one provides the greater effect?

For example, in my above screenshot, I have

1. **Power Efficiency II** in my armor slot, which increases my power recharge rate by 20%.
2. **Structural Ergonomics I** in my gear slot, which increases my power recharge rate by 5%.

With both of these equipped, will my power recharge rate now be 20% + 5% = 25% faster, or will only the 20% increase from Power Efficiency II apply?

Comment: I haven't played this in quite a while, but I recall them stacking. Hopefully someone has some evidence for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, they stack. If for example you got a Human Adept with 1 point assigned to Singularity and nothing else, with no weapons, gear or modules equipped, you get a recharge time of

**Recharge Speed: 2.67s** = 8(base value) / (1 + 2)

Where **2** =

- +2 Weight Cooldown Bonus

On the other hand, if you equip the gear and module you listed you get a recharge time of

**Recharge Speed: 2.46s** = 8(base value) / (1 + 2.25)

Where **2.25** =

- +0.2 Power Efficiency Module II
- +0.05 Structural Ergonomics I
- +2 Weight Cooldown Bonus

You can obtain all those numbers with a calculator, my favorite one is [Narida's](http://www.narida.pytalhost.com) which is where i took these values.